# Simple rails form helper error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

I'm still very new to rails and I'm trying to figure out what exactly I've done wrong here.

This is the error that I'm getting:

> undefined method `thoughts_path' for #<#:0x007fdcc176bbf0>

In addition to this Application Trace error:

> app/views/thoughts/create.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_thoughts_create_html_erb___4175069892643358175_70293055466360'

And here's a link to the source on Gist
https://gist.github.com/78037c4febfaa270a67e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does your routes(config/routes.rb) file look like ? Does it contain `resources :thoughts` ? If not, add it and see if it works.